# Apart from a good student, he is a good son too

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adverbs, spoken-english

I argue that the following sentence is grammatically correct:

---

***Apart from a good student, he is a good son too.***

Wouldn't it better to say:

---

**Apart from *being* a good student, he is a good son too.**

I feel the sentence a bit off without *'being'*.

---

Thanks!

Comment: Think of this as two separate sentences. What feels better, "He is a good student" or "He is being a good student" ? The phrase "Apart from" is just acting as a conjunction between these two sentences.

Comment: @BellaSwan Indeed. It is a conjunction. Why didn't I think so in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apart from *being* a good student, he is *also* a good son.

I would agree that the *being* is required in this case.

However I would also ask whether *apart* is the word you want to use. It is commonly held by some that good students are typically good sons. So perhaps something like:

> In addition to being a good student, he is also a good son.

In short:

- You are correct about *being*.
- I would swap the *too* for *also*
- Consider the meaning you are trying to convey with *apart*.

Comment: Thank you for your correction!

Comment: Yes. The sentence you suggested seems better. I am trying to say that 'Apart' is something like 'Besides" or "Other than".

Comment: Then apart is the  correct word to use, if that was your meaning then yes.